# Class library as embedded resource - can it be done?

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I have a .NET solution that I'm writing that the final result is a class library (I'm supposed to give the client a DLL file that he could reference and use in his project).

My solution includes:

- Class Library (let's call it MyClassLib) - this is the actual class library that I'm supposed to give to the client
- Tools Class Library - this class library contains tools that are not part of the actual MyClassLib but are used inside it (and therefor referenced by it)
- Console Application - to test MyClassLib (usless for the client)

When I publish, as expected, I get to DLL files - one for MyClassLib and one for Tools.

I only want to give the client one DLL file (MyClassLib) and that DLL will know how to use Tools even if it's not copied with it.

I was wondering if there's any way to embed the Tools reference inside MyClassLib. If so, how? if not, what would you have done in such a case?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) by Jeffrey Richter shows you how to do this.

Basically you use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to intercept the assembly load and return the assembly from a resource.

Alternatively you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), a utility that can combine multiple assemblies into a single file.

Comment: Using the AssemblyResolve approach in a lib/dll can be nasty to the end user. ILMerge or [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) is usually a better approach.

Comment: AssemblyRes is global to the AppDomain, staticly init at runtime, will be called for *every* type resolve error, can't be turned off/prioritized. Also unavailability to compilation env (e.g. VS may complain that it doesn't find the dependency libraries when you reference the one with such 'resolver')

Answer (score 3):

Old, but will post for future seekers.

Build a class like so:

```
class Extractor
{
    public static void ExtractResourceToFile(string resourceName, string filename)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
            using (System.IO.Stream s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[s.Length];
                s.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }
    }
}
```

Then, add

```
Extractor.ExtractResourceToFile("NAMESPACE.YOURDLL.dll", "YOURDLL.dll");
```

to your main file.

In order for this to work, simply **Add as existing file** , with the build action **Embedded resource**.

Works with any third party dlls, and you can of course use both dll import or referencing.

Comment: Very nice. Will definitely give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

I had amazing results with [LibZ](http://libz.codeplex.com/). You can just merge everything together. I used it to merge everything into an installer .exe, but it works for .dlls just as well.